# JavaScript live syntax highlighter

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, wysiwyg, live

Do you know a good live syntax highlighter written in JavaScript? With live syntax highlighter I mean a WYSIWYG editor that can be included in HTML pages and that is able to highlight the code in real time. Like a Notepad++ but in JavaScript.

I've already read this question: [Are there any JavaScript live syntax highlighters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655/are-there-any-javascript-live-syntax-highlighters)
but there's nothing that interests me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Bespin](https://bespin.mozilla.com/) which has an embeddable editor.

Answer (score 4):

Try [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/), which is used by JSBin and many other sites.