# What is the WYSIWYG editor used by Stackoverflow?

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

Is the editor used by Stackoverflow for textbox a Jquery plugin or is it a custom designed editor just for the site? Are there any alternatives to this editor. I mean a editor that has programming syntax friendly features and simple for users to use.

Comment: its WMD Markdown Editor  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26412/what-wysiwyg-editor-is-stack-overflow-using

Comment: Have you looked into [are-there-any-javascript-live-syntax-highlighters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655/are-there-any-javascript-live-syntax-highlighters)

Comment: @SDG-ShubhDasgupta The question are very old and the links on the answers are comming up as broken. Only one link worked but it dosent address anything.

Comment: @Ahmad the links are broken but googling it now.

Comment: I can see it on google code

Comment: @FloodGravemind [edit-control-on-stack-overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808/edit-control-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @Ahmad links on google code broken as well.

Comment: @SDG-ShubhDasgupta All broken they are 2008 questions.

Comment: @FloodGravemind: to answer your question, you can look into my above link(if not broken). As a suggestion, I would say go with [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/addons/), and text editor as [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/). So details can be found [here](http://www.wardenier.com/syntax-highlighting/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into [SyntaxHL plugin for Tinymce](https://github.com/RichGuk/syntaxhl)

From the mouth of developer:-

> SyntaxHL is a plugin for the Tinymce (http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)
>   javascript WYSIWYG editor allowing you to insert highlighted code into
>   the editor. The syntax highlighting is done using Syntax Highligher
>   (http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) and the plugin simply
>   produces the right syntax for this.

Lastly, what I know is a [**plugin syntaxhighlighter-plugin-for-tinymce-wysiwyg-editor.aspx**](http://weblogs.asp.net/nawaf/archive/2008/04/06/syntaxhighlighter-plugin-for-tinymce-wysiwyg-editor.aspx) from `Nawaf's Blog`, for which i don't have much idea(you can have a look though)!

**[Source code](http://weblogs.asp.net/nawaf/attachment/6071786.ashx)**

EDIT:-

Was just googling around and found one question in meta.stackoverflow, which is [what-wysiwyg-editor-is-stack-overflow-using](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26412/what-wysiwyg-editor-is-stack-overflow-using), over here someone posted a link [introducing-griffin-editor-a-jquery-textarea-plugin](http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/02/introducing-griffin-editor-a-jquery-textarea-plugin/#.UmY0wnCnpCY) which was quiet good to read and implement.

Just have a look if it helps!

Edit 2:-

While reading, I found people mentioning `WMD Editor` as the text-editor for stackoverflow. Which is not longer available in `wmd-editor.com`.

It was previously [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71822/wheres-the-wmd-editor-open-source-project?lq=1) but moved to GitHub, over [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown).

Comment: Thanks Shubh I am downloading TinyMCE using Nuget.

Comment: if you are looking for a WYSIWYG online editor you can use following link : https://askgif.com/editor/